# Is there any Nifi processor which can process data parallely?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have this data which I need to validate with the Api Response Data, I have written Execute Script for this But my case is Once `Sub_Id_1` will be matched with the API response then only the same APi will be called again to match the data of `Sub_Id_2`.

But I am stuck how will I come back to the `List`'s further index, here `List[1]`th index which is this

```json
{
  "Sub_Id_1": "Tech Support",
  "Sub_Id_2": "Manager"
}
```

.

If there will be only 1 index in List then it will work fine but for more than one index how will I Come back to next index data after 0th index processing is completed and it will move further to the next processor in the flow.

```json
[
  {
    "employerId": "98765",
    "location": "524",
    "empdept": "Management",
    "List": [
      {
        "Sub_Id_1": "HR",
        "Sub_Id_2": "Sr. Manager"
      },
      {
        "Sub_Id_1": "Tech Support",
        "Sub_Id_2": "Manager"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```